# でも、週明けすぐっていうのもね clarification

Tags: grammar

The following sentence should translate to "However, going at the beginning of the week is no good":

> でも、週明けすぐっていうのもね。

Still, what exactly in the sentence gives the idea of "no good"? Is it just でも? Would omitting でも change the meaning of the sentence? Or is there something on the のもね part too which gives that nuance to the phrase?
Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: How do you know it "should" translate to something? Please post your reasoning along with more context, because given just this information it's not possible to answer this question.

Comment: As you see in @mon's post, your sentence probably contains a typo (のも, not もの). Will you check the original? (Your post might get closed as off topic if the spelling mistake was the cause of your confusion.)

Answer (score 3):

It looks to be the same question as one answered on lang-8 (note: expired link removed), providing the sentence ends のもね instead of ものね.

> でも、週明けすぐっていうのもね。

Citing the answer. It explains that
"っていうのも" indicates the negative and omitting the following sentence.

> 「っていうのもね・・・」というのは、大まかに言うと、否定的な意味で使います。
> その後に続くsentenseが省略されています。
> はっきり言わずに、あいまいなまま濁して返事をする日本人の文化を表していると思います。

For example the complete sentence could be:

> 週明けすぐっていうのも早すぎると思う。

He/she thinks "it is too early/hasty (hence he/she does not want to" and by avoiding saying so directly is the way to indirectly express negative/no.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I made indeed a typo, sorry for the trouble. Nevertheless, is っていうのも a common grammar item? Even after browsing on the internet, I came across next to zero examples.

Comment: Google returns 1,330,000 hits for "っていうのも". It is commonly used.