# Meaning of ばっかっていうのもねえ

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of ばっかっていうのもねえ in the sentence: "せっかくヨットに乗るのに、　野郎ばっかっていうのもねえ"?

Comment: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38822/30454  https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/38394/30454

Answer (score 3):

ばっか = ばかり = only

っていうのもねえ = というのもね = shows dissatisfaction/disapproval of whatever precedes it

Therefore:

> せっかくヨットに乗るのに、野郎**ばっかっていうのもねえ**

translates into something along the lines of

> **Sucks that we're only** guys, now that we have the chance to sail on a yacht